# JSS - How to style a nested child?

Tags: reactjs, jss

I have a list and want to style a nested element of list-item from the parent. How can i access the nested element? The code below does not work.

react js mark up

```
<ul classname={classes.list}>
   <li>
     <span className={classes.box}> my box </span>
   </li>
   <li>
     <span className={classes.box}>second box </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JSS

```
const styles = () => ({
  box: {
    background: 'red',
  },
  list: {
    listStyle: "none",

    "li": {
      "&:first-child": {
        "& $box": {
          color: 'red',
          border: 'solid',
         }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is minor change in how you are `defining your styles object` which can get your code running. For nested elements you need to **seperate & and classname or dom item by** `space`

working style object:

```
const styles = () => ({
  box: {
    background: 'red',
  },
  list: {
    listStyle: "none",
    '& li': {
      '&:first-child': {
        '& $box': {
          border: 'solid',
        }
      }

    }
  }
})
```

[working demo](https://codepen.io/gauravAit/pen/gqyMNY)

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps:

JSS

```
list: {
    listStyle: "none",  
    '& li:first-child $box': {
      background: 'blue'
    }
  }
```

And you got a little typing error. It should be "className" with a capital "N".

Greetings

Comment: Thank you, but the box-className is part of the style-object, I updated it above. I think your solution is accessing a string-className

Comment: I edited my answer after i saw that. Just replace the . with a $ and it should work :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/vyz11lo88l